# Jetty Vs Tomcat for a JSF based social networking & sharing website

Tags: tomcat, java, jetty, application-server

I need to host my JavaServerFaces application which is a sort of networking & sharing website.

Which amongst Jetty & Tomcat is recommended for my app? Need easy scalability, better performance & low costs.

Comment: Keeping in mind that there is no license costs for both and that the scalability and performances will be more a function of your application code than anything else, my advice is to choose the one you're most familiar with. If you've developed your application on Tomcat, then keep using Tomcat for production, and the same thing about Jetty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We run multiple Java web apps on Tomcat with no issues. And we run them all on CentOS.